# Jenkins workspace directory verify if exist then build that project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have Bitbucket repository. There are multiple directory. I am using Jenkins parametrized job to build the each micro-services. There are two string parameter using one for services and second for environment.
I want to validate services name which i passed in the string paramter before executing the stage of that particular micr-service.

Like folder structure is:
service-one
service-two
service-three

if someone using wrong service name like services_one, service--one, serviceone then stage will not execute.

currently, I am passing two string paramters.
Fist:
Name: services
Value: service-one, service-two, service-three

Second:
Name: environment
Value: Dev

```
node{
    
    env.SERVICE_NAMES = params.services
    env.ENVIRONMENT = params.environment
    
    stage('clone'){
        git branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'repo-login', url: 'https://repo-urk/project/mutiple-servcies.git'
    }
    
    // Mulitple stages loop for services
    "${env.SERVICE_NAMES}".split(",").each { param ->
        service_name = "$param".trim()
        stage("${service_name}"){
            println "Stage executed for: ${service_name}"  
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You can use fileExists step like this: `if(fileExists(service_name))`.

Comment: Can you please put it in the stage so that I can use that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fileExists` like this:

```
node{
    
    env.SERVICE_NAMES = params.services
    env.ENVIRONMENT = params.environment
    
    stage('clone'){
        git branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'repo-login', url: 'https://repo-urk/project/mutiple-servcies.git'
    }
    
    // Mulitple stages loop for services
    "${env.SERVICE_NAMES}".split(",").each { param ->
        service_name = "$param".trim()

        if(fileExists(service_name)){
            stage("${service_name}"){
                println "Stage executed for: ${service_name}"  
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```